# Can't add <option> to <select> correctly using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've simple html code and dynamically adding some `<li>` elements to `#place` using this code

```js
$(function () {
    select = document.querySelector("select[name='selected-seats']");
    var settings = {
        rows: 4,
        cols: 12,
        rowCssPrefix: 'row-',
        colCssPrefix: 'col-',
        seatWidth: 45,
        seatHeight: 45,
        seatCss: 'seat',
        selectedSeatCss: 'selectedSeat',
        selectingSeatCss: 'selectingSeat'
    };

    var init = function (reservedSeat) {
        var str = [], seatNo, className;
        for (i = 0; i < settings.rows; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < settings.cols; j++) {
                seatNo = (i + j * settings.rows + 1);
                className = settings.seatCss + ' ' + settings.rowCssPrefix + i.toString() + ' ' + settings.colCssPrefix + j.toString();
                if ($.isArray(reservedSeat) && $.inArray(seatNo, reservedSeat) != -1) {
                    className += ' ' + settings.selectedSeatCss;
                }
                str.push('<li class="' + className + '"' +
                'style="top:' + (i * settings.seatHeight).toString() + 'px;left:' + (j * settings.seatWidth).toString() + 'px">' +
                '<a title="' + seatNo + '">' + seatNo + '</a>' +
                '</li>');
            }
        }
        $('#place').html(str.join(''));
    };          
    init();

    $('.' + settings.seatCss).click(function () {    
        if ($(this).hasClass(settings.selectedSeatCss)){
            alert('This seat is already reserved');
        }
        else {
            var str = [], item;
            $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectedSeatCss + ' a, #place li.'+ settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
                    
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                    
                option.value = str.push($(this).attr('title'));; 
                option.text =  str.push($(this).attr('title'));;
                option.selected = 'selected';
                select.appendChild(option);
            });
                
            $(this).toggleClass(settings.selectingSeatCss);
        }
    });

    $('#btnShow').click(function () {
        var str = [];
        $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectedSeatCss + ' a, #place li.'+ settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
            str.push($(this).attr('title'));
        });
        alert(str.join(','));
    })

    $('#btnShowNew').click(function () {
        var str = [], item;
        $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
            item = $(this).attr('title');                   
            str.push(item);                   
        });
        alert(str.join(','));
    })
});
```

```css
    #holder{    
      height:200px;   
      width:550px;
      background-color:#F5F5F5;
      border:1px solid #A4A4A4;
      margin-left:10px;  
    }
    #place {
      position:relative;
      margin:7px;
    }
    #place a{
      font-size:0.6em;
    }
    #place li{
      list-style: none outside none;
      position: absolute;   
    }    
    #place li:hover {
      background-color:yellow;      
    } 
    #place .seat{
      background:url("img") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
      height:33px;
      width:33px;
      display:block;  
    }
    #place .selectedSeat{ 
      background-image:url("img");          
    }
    #place .selectingSeat{ 
      background-image:url("img");        
    }
    #place .row-3, #place .row-4{
      margin-top:10px;
    }
    #seatDescription{
      padding:0px;
    }
    #seatDescription li{
      verticle-align:middle;      
      list-style: none outside none;
      padding-left:35px;
      height:35px;
      float:left;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selected-seats" ></select><br><br>
<div id="place"></div>
```

at lines

```
$.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectedSeatCss + ' a, #place li.'+ settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {

    var option = document.createElement("option");

    option.value = str.push($(this).attr('title'));; 
    option.text =  str.push($(this).attr('title'));;
    option.selected = 'selected';
    select.appendChild(option);
});
```

I have couple of issues:
 
1- I can not find a way to get title of selected seat
2- I can not find a way to get child of select element removed if it is un-selected

For a working demo of app with clear understanding, Please visit [Here](http://brs-escot.rhcloud.com/)

Can any one suggest me a solution to that need.

Comment: your code seems fine to me, but have you tried calling `$(this).selectmenu("refresh");` after appending the option (on your second last line of code you showed us here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script and check it may work for you,

```
<script>
    $(function () {

                select = document.querySelector("select[name='selected-seats']");
                var settings = {
                    rows: 4,
                    cols: 12,
                    rowCssPrefix: 'row-',
                    colCssPrefix: 'col-',
                    seatWidth: 45,
                    seatHeight: 45,
                    seatCss: 'seat',
                    selectedSeatCss: 'selectedSeat',
                    selectingSeatCss: 'selectingSeat'
                };

                var init = function (reservedSeat) {
                    var str = [], seatNo, className;
                    for (i = 0; i < settings.rows; i++) {
                        for (j = 0; j < settings.cols; j++) {
                            seatNo = (i + j * settings.rows + 1);
                            className = settings.seatCss + ' ' + settings.rowCssPrefix + i.toString() + ' ' + settings.colCssPrefix + j.toString();
                            if ($.isArray(reservedSeat) && $.inArray(seatNo, reservedSeat) != -1) {
                                className += ' ' + settings.selectedSeatCss;
                            }
                            str.push('<li class="' + className + '"' +
                                      'style="top:' + (i * settings.seatHeight).toString() + 'px;left:' + (j * settings.seatWidth).toString() + 'px">' +
                                      '<a title="' + seatNo + '">' + seatNo + '</a>' +
                                      '</li>');
                        }
                    }
                    $('#place').html(str.join(''));
                };          
                init();


                $('.seat').click(function () {                  

                    if ( $( this ).hasClass( "selectingSeat" ) ) {
                        $(this).removeClass("selectingSeat");
                    }else{
                        $(this).addClass("selectingSeat");
                    }
                    options="";
                    $("#place .seat").each(function () {
                        if ( $( this ).hasClass( "selectingSeat" ) ) {
                            options+="<option>"+$( this ).find("a").attr("title")+"</option>";
                        }
                    });

                    $("[name='selected-seats']").html(options);
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: OK this looks promising, but this code adds two elements of `<option>` tag one with value and other empty one see https://jsfiddle.net/dmncv9em/6/

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks a lot

Comment: Put an explanation of what was wrong with the original code and how you fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that function you specified separately, Can you Try this:-

```
$('.' + settings.seatCss).click(function () {

 if ($(this).hasClass(settings.selectedSeatCss)){
     alert('This seat is already reserved');
}
else{
  $(this).addClass(settings.selectedSeatCss)
  var str = [], item;
  select.innerHTML = "";
  $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectedSeatCss + ' a, #place li.'+ settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.value = $(this).attr('title'); 
     option.text =  $(this).attr('title');
     option.selected = 'selected';
     select.appendChild(option);
 });

            $(this).toggleClass(settings.selectingSeatCss);
            }
        });
```

You missed Two Things.

1. If the selected seat is not having the  `selectedSeatCss` , you are not adding it.
2. You are not clearing the select drop down after each selection, instead you are appending every time.

Comment: @ArshadAli check now. I have made two changes to your function